# In Gherkin syntax, what's the difference between Example and Scenario?

Tags: gherkin

On their website: https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/

It lists Example (or Scenario) under keywords. Is there a difference, or can everything that can be done with one keyword, be done with the other?

Answer (score 0):

Scenario is a test with steps.
Scenario Outline is for a scenario that you want to loop through with table data, Example is the heading of that table.

```
Scenario: Test something
  Given I am logged in
  And I select the "Add" tab
  And I select the "New" button
  Then the form is displyed

Scenario Outline: Test something else
  Given I am logged in as "<user>"
  And I select the "Add" tab
  And I select the "<item>" button
  Then the form is displyed
Examples:
    | user | item |
    | aaaa | Add  |
    | bbbb | Edit |
```

Comment: Close, I found the answer. Note: the heading of the table is "Examples" not "Example." There's a line in the Gherkin Syntax documentation that states that "Example" is a synonym for "Scenario."