# Can DataTable and Parameter be used at the same time in Cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

Something I've been running into several times now.

Example:

```
  Scenario: When I flick the switch, different colors appear
    Given that the electricity bill is paid
    When switch flicked is true
      | blue  |
      | green |
      | red   |
    Then the lightbulb should show red at the end
```

And the following step definition (Given and When are not relevant for the question):

```
@When("switchFlicked is {}")
public void switchFlickedIs(boolean isSwitchFlicked, DataTable dataTable) {
    DiscoLight.setColours(dataTable.asList());
    DiscoLight.setSwitch(isSwitchFlicked);
}
```

Can both parameters and data tables be used at the same time? If so: how? Because the above will not work.

Comment: Firstly, your syntax is not correct, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64424395/3355860) for an example. Then, maybe put true/false in the table.

Comment: Not much wrong with the syntax, you can put a table there. Putting the boolean in the middle doesn't change. (Example works when I only use the boolean, or only use the datatable, but not both at the same time.)

Comment: U can try by specifying the parameter type. Try this in the feature file - `When switch flicked is 'true'`. And the step def method - `@Given("When switch flicked is {string}") - public void switchFlickedIs(String value, DataTable dataTable)`

Comment: Try using Scenario Outline and example table. You can pass the value in the example table and use it Feature as "<color>" where color is one of the columns in your example table having different colors in row

Answer (score 2):

> Can both parameters and data tables be used at the same time?

Yes.

> If so: how? Because the above will not work.

Note that your step is: `switch flicked is true` while your step definition is: `switchFlicked is {}`. This is effectively the same as writing the regex `^switchFlicked is (.*)$`. Because the space and capitalization matter this regex will never match your step.

Instead try using:

```java
@When("switch flicked is {}")
public void switchFlickedIs(boolean isSwitchFlicked, DataTable dataTable) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scenario Outline: When I flick the switch, different colors appear Given that the electricity bill is paid When switch flicked is "" | blue | | green | | red | Then the lightbulb should show "" at the end

Example |TC|SwitchState|Color| |1|True|Red|

StepDeinition

---

``````
@When("switch flicked is {string}")
public String switchFlickedIs(String SwitchState,List<String>colors){
   String Set Color= "";
   If SwitchState.equals(true){
    for(int i=0; i<colors.size();i++){
      SetColor= colors.get(i)
     }
    retutn SetColor; 
   }else 
    return SetColor;
}

@Then("Then the lightbulb should show {string} at the end")
public void VerifyLightbulb color(String FinalColor){
  Assert.equals(FinalColor,SetColor, "Final Color is not red");
}
`````
``````

Comment: This did not work for me. The Step is expecting only one argument -> string, but the definition has two arguments -> String and List<>.
Got the below exception:
 io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Step [switch flicked is {string}] is defined with 2 parameters at 'stepdefinitions.Test_Steps.switchFlickedIs(java.lang.String,io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable)'.
However, the gherkin step has 1 arguments